# Bing Maps API v8 click event on multiple segment polyline created with WKT module

Tags: bing-maps

I'm creating a multiple segment polyline on the JavaScript Bing Maps API v8 (I'm adding some hundreds of those multiple segment polylines to the map, here I simplified the code), using the Well Known Text module. The WKT returns an array of lines, and they are added to the map. I need to bind the 'click' mouse event to the entire multi segment object, not to every segment of the line.

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    credentials: 'yourCredentials', center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.9502426, -95.398039), zoom: 5 });

dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
map.layers.insert(dataLayer);

Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.WellKnownText', function () {
     var line = Microsoft.Maps.WellKnownText.read('MULTILINESTRING((-102.562979 33.469944, -102.562964 33.469944)(-84.6725847 31.7707373, -84.6556331 31.7698178))');

     //the following line doesn't work, returns an error because there is no 'add' on the line array
     Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(line, 'click', function (args) { console.log(args); });

     //this loops works, but the when event fires returns as 'target' only a subsegment of the entire multiple segment line
     for (var elem in line) {
          Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(line[elem], 'click', function (args) { console.log(args); });
     }

     dataLayer.add(line);
});
```

Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the event to the layer itself? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-api/layer-class

If you need to have different handlers for different lines, you can still access the shape interacted with and differentiate next steps in the callback function.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work for me, since I have several hundred of those multisegment polylines. If I add all those lines to one layer, then the layer event is going to return all the objects inside that layer. Maybe if I create one layer for each multisegment line, but that means hundreds of layers. Definitely Bing Maps API will not work for my purposes. I better use leaflet with the plugin to load bing maps basemaps.

Comment: The target or primitive property on the layer click event is the single shape user interacts with, which in your case is a line segment.

Comment: On leaflet, when you click on any segment of a multisegment polyline, returns the multisegment object, unlike bing, that returns only one polyline.